# Using setTimeout inside onChange in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

**NOTE: I formulated this question poorly. Initially I wanted to ask about something else, but since this happened, I marked the only answer as correct.**

I tried to add a delay for an action that is triggered by changing the input's value. I needed to fire this action after 2 seconds since the user writes the last character into the input.

Firstly, I tried to write something like that:

```
onChange={(e) => {
   const timeoutFn = setTimeout(() => {
     // This func triggers rerender of the component
     onInputChange(e.target.value);
   }, 2000);
   return () => clearTimeout(timeoutFn);
}}
```

This approach didn't work, so I used `useEffect` instead and it worked perfectly. However, now I'm interested in the strange behavior of `setTimout` inside the `onChange`'s handler.

When I use `setTimeout` inside the `onChange`, the `onInputChange` fires only **once** after 2 seconds since the user **starts typing**. At the same time, `e.target.value` contains the last value entered by the user.

Why does it work like that and not the same as `setTimout` works in `useEffect`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, now I'm interested in the strange behavior of `setTimout` inside the `onChange`'s handler.

To React nothing is happening with your current code is as if it's `onChange={(e) => {}}` because state is ***not*** updating immediately meaning re-rendering is ***not*** happening and `e.target.value` remains `""`. (*NOTE*: *even* `0`ms won't update the state immediately, because of the asynchronous nature of the `setTimeout` and how Event Loop works (you can check links below).)

> When I use `setTimeout` inside the `onChange`, the `onInputChange` fires only *once* after 2 seconds since the user starts typing.

It doesn't really fire only once, the callback from `setTimeout` runs after *2 seconds* (*2000 ms*) for as many times as the amount of characters entered in the `input` (*even though `input` is not updating*). You can verify this it by calling `console.count('callback fired')` inside the callback fn of `setTimeout`.

> At the same time, `e.target.value` contains the last value entered by the user.

Yes, if you `console.log(e.target.value)` inside `onChange` it will indeed print the last entered character at the time when a user entered a character, but since update is ***not*** happening meaning React component is ***not*** re-rendering meaning the `input`'s `value` prop remains the *initial value*. By the time `setTimeout`'s *delay* has passed (*2000ms*) the callback is called, then `onInputChange(e.target.value)` is called where the `e.target.value` equals to `""` (*empty string* or any initial value), so what happens is this: `onInputChange("")` is called and re-rendering is ***not*** happening when React sees no changes.

As a side-note you don't need `return () => clearTimeout(timeoutFn)` because that does nothing; if you meant to `clearTimeout(timeoutFn)` (with or without `return`) the `setTimeout` won't run as it will be cleared (*canceled*) before its *delay* has finished.

You can see my code sample: [image: Edit busy-rui-sbne8y].

Links about the Event Loop:

- [YouTube: Call stack, heap, queue, event loop - Talk.JS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qe0IKzAB1OE)
- [Understanding the JavaScript runtime environment](https://medium.com/@gemma.croad/understanding-the-javascript-runtime-environment-4dd8f52f6fca)